# How to detect if a ListView is fast scrolling

Tags: android, listview, fastscroll

Is there a way to detect if a ListView is fast scrolling? That is to say, can we somehow know when the user presses and releases the FastScroller?

Answer (score 6):

Reflection allows you to do it. By taking a look at the [AbsListView source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java), there is a `FastScroller` object which indicates a wrapper around the fast scrolling functionality. [Its source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/FastScroller.java) shows an interesting [field](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/FastScroller.java#178):

```
/**
 * Current decoration state, one of:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link #STATE_NONE}, nothing visible
 * <li>{@link #STATE_VISIBLE}, showing track and thumb
 * <li>{@link #STATE_DRAGGING}, visible and showing preview
 * </ul>
 */
private int mState;
```

This field contains the status of the `FastScroller` object. The solution consists in reading this field's value via reflection, every time the `onScroll()` and `onScrollStateChanged()` methods are triggered.

This code implements the solution described above:

```
private class CustomScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

    private ListView list;
    private int mState = -1;
    private Field stateField = null;
    private Object mFastScroller;
    private int STATE_DRAGGING;

    public CustomScrollListener() {
        super();

        String fastScrollFieldName = "mFastScroller";
        // this has changed on Lollipop
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            fastScrollFieldName = "mFastScroll";
        }

        try {
            Field fastScrollerField = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField(fastScrollFieldName);
            fastScrollerField.setAccessible(true);
            mFastScroller = fastScrollerField.get(list);

            Field stateDraggingField = mFastScroller.getClass().getDeclaredField("STATE_DRAGGING");
            stateDraggingField.setAccessible(true);
            STATE_DRAGGING = stateDraggingField.getInt(mFastScroller);

            stateField = mFastScroller.getClass().getDeclaredField("mState");
            stateField.setAccessible(true);
            mState = stateField.getInt(mFastScroller);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        // update fast scroll state
        try {
            if (stateField != null) {
                mState = stateField.getInt(mFastScroller);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (mState == STATE_DRAGGING)) {
            // the user is fast scrolling through the list
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        // update fast scroll state
        try {
            if (stateField != null) {
                mState = stateField.getInt(mFastScroller);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the field "grid" in fastScrollerField.get(grid);   Also is there any disadvantages to using this, i assume reflections makes this 'slow'

Comment: `grid` is the GridView that I was using. I'm changing that to `list`, so to be more clear.

Comment: Also assuming this might break if the source is changed from sdk to sdk? and therefore the try catch. seems like a hacky solution

Comment: Yes, it is hacky, and yes, it has changed already, but only once. I'm updating the answer with the two variants. IMO, this is the only viable approach.

Comment: Right so it works! Brilliant! +1 But like you said it has changed so that the field variable is now "mFastScroll". Got to be a better way hummm

Comment: The thing is that now we have `RecyclerView` as the main list, and that does not support fast scrolling out of the box. Mark Hallison is writing a nice series of articles on this very subject: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/recyclerview-fastscroll-part-1/

Comment: This unfortunately does not work anymore on API 28 (Pie) if using targetSdkVersion=28, because "mState" is on the dark grey-list, resulting in NoSuchFieldException when trying to access that field.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the setOnScrollListener and implement the onScrollStateChanged. The scrollState can be idle, touch scroll, or fling

```
setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(scrollState == 2) Log.i("a", "fast scroll");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't mean it's fast tho. This will trigger scroll even if the user flings with little acceleration.

Comment: Are you trying to determine how fast it's scrolling?

Comment: I tried that already and scrolling touching the screen or scrolling the fastScroller return the same scrollState. I am using JazzyListView with a SLIDE_IN effect and have fast scrolling enabled in the ListView. When I fast scroll it does not work quite right because the first or last visible items are many times not visible. I wanted disable the effect when entering the fast scroll mode and re-enable it when leaving it.

Comment: It appears like there isn't a way to determine when fast scroll is used. there is a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7393) about it that says a fix is already released, but I can't find anything in the docs about it.