# Avoid SwipeRefresh while fastScrolling in android

Tags: android, android-listview, fastscroll

I have a **`ListView`** having `fastScroll` always enabled and `SwipeRefresh` implementation. When i swipe the list downward, it refreshes the list. My problem is `fastScroll`. If the list has its first item visible or say at its initial top, then if scroll the `fastScrollThumb` downward, it does the **`Swipe`** effect not the scroll down. Is there anyway/solution that if i press the `fastScrollThumb` , then it should not do `Swipe` refresh effect rather it should scroll down as it natural behavior.

[image]

**EDITED**
My `XML Layout` is as follow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"> 

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/SubmitButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/neoo_tab_selector" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            style="@style/NeeoContactListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttons_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

My **`Logic for onScroll`** for enabling/disabling the **`SwipeRefresh`** is :

```
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        boolean enable = false;
        if(getListView() != null && getListView().getChildCount() > 0){
            // check if the first item of the list is visible
            boolean firstItemVisible = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
            // check if the top of the first item is visible
            boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = getListView().getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
            // enabling or disabling the refresh layout
            enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
        }
        if(enable){
            enableSwipe();

        }else{
            disableSwipe();

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: your listview should have then > `listView.setOnScrollListener(...)`

Comment: i am already using  `listView.setOnScrollListener(...)` in which m using `onScroll` method mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just looked into [**the documentation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) of the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and I think they mention what you are looking for:

> ... If the listener determines there should not be a refresh, it must
>   call `setRefreshing(false)` to cancel any visual indication of a
>   refresh. If an activity wishes to show just the progress animation, it
>   should call `setRefreshing(true)`. To disable the gesture and progress
>   animation, call `setEnabled(false)` on the view.

So you have a few options, I would first try playing around with `setEnabled()` or `setRefreshing()`, but to properly use those methods we first need to be able to detect if the `ListView` is fast scrolling. There is no listener or anything for fast scrolling but you can get the state through reflection! Based on [**this excellent and seriously underrated answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24513340/2310866) I have written a `FastScrollListener` which can be used just like a `OnScrollListener`:

```
this.listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
this.listView.setOnScrollListener(new FastScrollListener(this.listView) {

    @Override
    protected void onFastScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, FastScrollState state) {
        // This line disabled the SwipeRefreshLayout  
        // whenever the user is fast scrolling
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(state != FastScrollState.DRAGGING);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFastScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    }
});
```

You could also try calling `setRefreshing()` instead of `setEnabled()` if `setEnabled()` doesn't work.

And here is the code of the `FastScrollListener`:

```
public abstract class FastScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private final int STATE_DRAGGING;
    private final int STATE_VISIBLE;
    private final int STATE_NONE;

    public enum FastScrollState {
        DRAGGING,
        VISIBLE,
        NONE,
        UNKNOWN
    }

    private FastScrollState fastScrollState = FastScrollState.UNKNOWN;
    private Field stateField;
    private Object mFastScroller;

    public FastScrollListener(AbsListView listView) {
        try {
            final Field fastScrollerField = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroller");
            fastScrollerField.setAccessible(true);
            mFastScroller = fastScrollerField.get(listView);

            final Field stateDraggingField = mFastScroller.getClass().getDeclaredField("STATE_DRAGGING");
            stateDraggingField.setAccessible(true);
            STATE_DRAGGING = stateDraggingField.getInt(mFastScroller);

            final Field stateVisibleField = mFastScroller.getClass().getDeclaredField("STATE_VISIBLE");
            stateVisibleField.setAccessible(true);
            STATE_VISIBLE = stateVisibleField.getInt(mFastScroller);

            final Field stateNoneField = mFastScroller.getClass().getDeclaredField("STATE_NONE");
            stateNoneField.setAccessible(true);
            STATE_NONE = stateNoneField.getInt(mFastScroller);

            stateField = mFastScroller.getClass().getDeclaredField("mState");
            stateField.setAccessible(true);
            fastScrollState = getFastScrollState();

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find required fields for fast scroll detection!", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find required fields for fast scroll detection!", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        updateFastScrollState(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        updateFastScrollState(view);
        updateFastScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
    }

    private void updateFastScrollState(AbsListView view) {
        if (stateField != null) {
            final FastScrollState state = getFastScrollState();
            if (fastScrollState != state) {
                fastScrollState = state;
                onFastScrollStateChanged(view, state);
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateFastScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if(fastScrollState == FastScrollState.DRAGGING) {
            onFastScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    private FastScrollState getFastScrollState() {

        try {
            final int state = stateField.getInt(mFastScroller);

            if (state == STATE_DRAGGING) {
                return FastScrollState.DRAGGING;
            }

            if (state == STATE_VISIBLE) {
                return FastScrollState.VISIBLE;
            }

            if (state == STATE_NONE) {
                return FastScrollState.NONE;
            }

            return FastScrollState.UNKNOWN;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not read fast scroll state!", e);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void onFastScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, FastScrollState state);

    protected abstract void onFastScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount);
}
```

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions please feel free to ask!

---

**EDIT:** Try this, but I doubt it will work:

```
@Override
protected void onFastScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, FastScrollState state) {
    boolean enable = false;
    if (getListView().getChildCount() > 0) {
        boolean firstItemVisible = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
        boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = getListView().getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
        enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
    }
    refreshLayout.setEnabled(enable);
}
```

Comment: Error on public enum FastScrollStat{...}
**"The member enum FastScrollState must be defined inside a static member type"**

Comment: That's because you nested `FastScrollListener` inside of another class. If you want to nest `FastScrollListener` you have to make it static like this: `public static abstract class FastScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener { ... }`.

Comment: Now when i drag, the `thumb` gets stuck at **`A`**/initial position and never gets down

Comment: But you can still fast scroll?

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. Anyway your logic seems kind of weird. If the `ListView` is scrolled all the way to the top you check if the user is scrolling (which in itself already is a contradiction because if the user were scrolling the `ListView` wouldn't be scrolled all the way to the top) and if the `ListView` isn't scrolled all the way to the top you disabled fast scrolling outright. Somethings definitely not right here, what do you want to do in this part of the code?

Comment: And do you really need fast scrolling? Fast scrolling is not a very good UI element. If you present so much information that fast scrolling is required than you are simply displaying too much information. It's the reason why no Google Apps have fast scrolling. Have you considered implementing a search instead? Fast scrolling is not very customisable and you have to prepare yourself for the possibility that this cannot be fixed so easily, if at all...

Comment: Thnx, My logic in `FastScrollStateChange` was very poor thats why i was stuck. Moreover, i was not implementing `onScrollStateChange`. But now its working.

Comment: Hi @Xaver Kapeller, can u plz take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196894/how-to-get-list-item-data-in-bindview-when-clicking-on-radiobutton-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Fast scroll in recyclerveiew was added in api 26.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#26-0-0.

If you want to use it pre api 26 use

https://github.com/L4Digital/FastScroll

This library has builtin fastscroll and it has a scroll listener that can disable the refreshview layout on scrolling

The developer addresses the problem here:

https://github.com/L4Digital/FastScroll/issues/14

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @M66B really ??

Comment: Really, because the question was how to avoid swipe refresh on fast scrolling and your answer doesn't address that at all. Even if the links contains the answer somehow, you should answer the question here and not by giving a link, see the rules.

Comment: thats what the library does. it has scroll listeners where u can stop the swipe to refresh